How do I search through a dict using user's input as a key inside a nested dict?
Working on my final project for cs50 Introduction to programming with Python. Trying to implement a programm with a few functions, such as: calculating basal metabolic rate, formatting a list of products, printing a nutritional value of a user specified product and suggesting/sorting products by their value depending on a macronutrient specified by user.
Having trouble with the latter function.
I have a two-level deep dict of different products with their nutritional value:
products = {
    "almonds": {"protein": 6.0, "fat": 14.2, "carbs": 6.1, "fiber": 3.5, "calories": 164},
    "banana": {"protein": 1.3, "fat": 0.4, "carbs": 27.0, "fiber": 3.1, "calories": 105},
    "buckwheat": {"protein": 5.7, "fat": 1.0, "carbs": 34.0, "fiber": 4.5, "calories": 155},
    "ground beef": {"protein": 24.0, "fat": 13, "carbs": 0, "fiber": 0, "calories": 218}
}

I want to implement a function which asks the user for a macronutrient (protein, fat, carbs, fiber or calories - all are the keys for a nested dict), searches through the products dict and then outputs a top-three products, based on their nutritional value specified by user.
I am having trouble with sorting the dict by it's value (as I see it). Thought about storing the value as a nested list:
products = {"banana": [1.3, 0.4, 27.0, 3.1, 105]}

So I can call a value by:
product = input("Name of a product: ").lower().strip()
macro = input("Name of a macronutrient: ").lower().strip()
# using macro variable and if statements to specify the index of a list
if macro == "protein":
    products.keys(product)[0] # running into a problem when calling product here

But the products dict seems kind of cryptic anyway, so I would like to avoid this option.
As of now I have the following function:
def _get_nested_val(data, *args):
    if args and data:
        element  = args[0]
        if element:
            value = data.get(element)
            return value if len(args) == 1 else _get_nested_val(value, *args[1:])

I call this function in main() for showing the user a nutritional value of a specific product:
    elif initial == "show specifics":
            product = input("Enter a name of the product: ").lower().strip()
            call = input("Enter a macronutrient: ").lower().strip()
            if call == "protein" or call == "fat" or call == "carbs" or call == "fiber":
                print(_get_nested_val(products, product, call), "grams of", call, "in", product.capitalize())
            elif call == "calories":
                print(_get_nested_val(products, product, call), "calories in", product.capitalize())

I was wondering if I can use _get_nested_val() function to sort and output a few products, specified by user's input.
def main():
    initial = input("What do you want the programm to do? ").lower().strip()
    ... # other functions are called here, not relevant to the current problem
    elif initial == "suggest":
        suggest()

def suggest():
    req = input("Based on what macronutrient would you like the products to be suggested? ")
    if request == "protein":
    ...

### I would like to see the programm running like something this:
# $ What do you want the programm to do? suggest
# $ Based on what macronutrient would you like the products to be suggested? protein
# The following products are high in protein: Beef, Chicken breast, ...

I have checked a lot of other questions on Stack Overflow but fail to get my programm to work as I want it to.

seems like your data can naturally fit in a table - rows are products, columns are nutrient catagories. I suggest you read up on pandas library

Please add more entries in your dictionary, show user input and the output you want

Your starting point should be to develop a class that supports the nutritional values. That will make your code more concise and easier to maintain.
The problem you're having (as I understand it) is that you want user input of a macronutrient (e.g., fat, carbs) then sort your products dictionary based on the macronutrient value.
If that's the case then:
from collections import UserDict

class Nutrients(UserDict):
    MN = ["protein", "fat", "carbs", "fibre", "calories"]

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        assert len(args) == len(Nutrients.MN)
        self.data.update(zip(Nutrients.MN, args))

products: dict[str, Nutrients] = {
    "almonds": Nutrients(6.0, 14.2, 6.1, 3.5, 164),
    "banana": Nutrients(1.3, 0.4, 27.0, 3.1, 105),
    "buckwheat": Nutrients(5.7, 1.0, 34.0, 4.5, 155),
    "ground beef": Nutrients(24.0, 13, 0, 0, 218),
}

mn = input("Input macronutrient: ")

if mn in Nutrients.MN:
    print(f"The following are high in {mn}:")
    for p, _ in sorted(products.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][mn], reverse=True):
        print(f"\t{p.capitalize()}")

Terminal:
Input macronutrient: protein
The following are high in protein:
        Ground beef
        Almonds
        Buckwheat
        Banana


Thank you for your answer. I thought about using a custom class, but for some reason decided against it. For if statement I can use reverse as mentioned by @simon to print the list in descending order, right? Also, while having an output as a list, I would prefer to format it as a str (get rid of {} and ()), but simple .replce method wouldn't work, would it?

@Jötunn It's unclear (to me) what you want the output to look like

Something among the lines:
`print("The following products are high in", mn, ": \n", *result)
The following products are high in protein:
Ground beef
Buckwheat
Almonds
Banana
`

@Jötunn Answer edited

Thank you, the output looks just the way I imagined it to be.

This is an answer specifically to your question: I want to implement a function which asks the user for a macronutrient (protein, fat, carbs, fiber or calories - all are the keys for a nested dict), searches through the products dict and then outputs a top-three products, based on their nutritional value specified by user.
If you don't want to use an additional library, the following should do the job:
def top_k(prods: dict, nutrient: str, k: int) -> list[str]:
    higher_is_better = {"protein": True, "fat": False, "carbs": True,
                        "fiber": True, "calories": False}
    sort_key = lambda item: prods[item][nutrient]
    return sorted(prods.keys(), key=sort_key,
                  reverse=higher_is_better[nutrient])[:k]

Here is a usage example:
products = {
    "banana": {"protein": 1.3, "fat": 0.4, "carbs": 27.0, "fiber": 3.1, "calories": 105},
    "apple": {"protein": 0.3, "fat": 0.2, "carbs": 13.8, "fiber": 2.4, "calories": 52},
    "orange": {"protein": 0.9, "fat": 0.1, "carbs": 11.8, "fiber": 2.4, "calories": 47},
    "strawberry": {"protein": 0.7, "fat": 0.3, "carbs": 7.7, "fiber": 2.0, "calories": 32},
    "mango": {"protein": 0.8, "fat": 0.4, "carbs": 15.0, "fiber": 1.6, "calories": 60},
    "pineapple": {"protein": 0.5, "fat": 0.1, "carbs": 13.1, "fiber": 1.4, "calories": 50}
}

def top_k(prods: dict, nutrient: str, k: int) -> list[str]:
    higher_is_better = {"protein": True, "fat": False, "carbs": True,
                        "fiber": True, "calories": False}
    sort_key = lambda item: prods[item][nutrient]
    return sorted(prods.keys(), key=sort_key,
                  reverse=higher_is_better[nutrient])[:k]

print(top_k(products, "fat", k=2))
# >>> ['orange', 'pineapple']
print(top_k(products, "protein", k=3))
# >>> ['banana', 'orange', 'mango']

Here is how it works:

With higher_is_better, we define for each macro-nutrient, whether a higher or lower value is better. Here, I work with the (probably somewhat stereotypical) assumption that the users are looking for high-protein, low-fat, high-carbs, high-fiber, or low-calorie products. Of course, this might not be the case. To change this, either provide your own fixed values of higher_is_better or let the users provide the corresponding boolean themselves, defining what is "top" for them, as an additional input.
With sort_key, we define the sorting criterion: The items we want to sort are the keys of the outer dictionary, the criterion is the nutrient's value.
We sort the keys of the outer dict by this criterion and return the top k results (k=3 in your case). Depending on the corresponding value in higher_is_better, we set the reverse parameter to achieve ascending or descending order as necessary.

In general I would agree with one of the comments though, namely, that using pandas for similar use cases would be the better option.
Update: Regarding the question from your comment below, as to how to make use of the results list from top_k(). You can use the list to query the products dictionary again, and then provide the output in the form you desire, for example like so:
macronutrient = "protein"
top_prods = top_k(products, macronutrient, k=3)
print(f"Top products regarding {macronutrient} content:",
      ", ".join(f"{p} ({products[p][macronutrient]})" for p in top_prods))

This will print
Top products regarding protein content: banana (1.3), orange (0.9), mango (0.8)


Thank you for your answer. I am not sure why we should store macros in a list when defining top_k() function though. Can you ellaborate a bit further, please?
Regarding pandas - I have seen quite a few questions with somewhat similiar problems with suggested answers being "use pandas", but as I see it - while there are no mention of pandas in my cs50 course - I thought I should try and solve my own problem set without it.

@Jötunn With why we should store macros in a list when defining top_k(), are you referring to the return value of top_k()? My idea here is that you get the top-3 products that you are asking for (quote from your question: "… outputs a top-three products"), in their correct order, and then can do what you want with them in a next step.

I get it now, thank you.

You can use this resulting list then to access your products dict again. For example, if you want to show the top-3 protein products, you can do nutrient = "protein", then found_prods = top_k(products, nutrient, k=3), then for prod in found_prods: print(f"{products[prod][nutrient]} {nutrient} in {prod}")

Understood, thank you once again.
